# Forwarding to unwanted site

Tags: apache, ubuntu, odoo

I host an Odoo instance (website) on an Ubuntu server which I access through a `.dyndns.org` address via `port 8069`. 
Recently I was attempting to make a SSL certificate and since then I am unable to access the Odoo instance over WAN, instead browser windows redirect to my business website which is hosted by a commercial company. I am able to access the Odoo instance on the LAN. Obviously I have done something, but I don't know what. How do I stop Apache forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Nginx as reverse proxy : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/nginx-reverse-proxy-on-80-443-32052